# Adding a custom property to IdbConnection.connectionString - c#

Tags: c#, connection-string

I am working on c# code which should edit the connectionString with new user and password.
since there are several operation of Open the connection, I need to handle an indication if the connectionString was already overwritten or not.

I tried add a new property to the connection string for this indication:

```
public string setUserAndPassword(IDbConnection dbConnection,string user, string password)
    {
        DbConnectionStringBuilder sb = new DbConnectionStringBuilder();
        sb.ConnectionString= dbConnection.ConnectionString;
        sb.Add("user id", user);
        sb.Add("password", password);
        sb.Add("authenticated", true);
        return sb.ConnectionString;

    }
```

and update the new connectionString here:

```
string newConnectionString = vendor.setUserAndPassword(dbConnection, dbCredentials.getUser(), dbCredentials.getPassword());
            dbConnection.ConnectionString = newConnectionString;
```

But seems that it's impossible to add a custom property because last line fails with exception:
System.ArgumentException: 'Keyword not supported: 'authenticated'.'

(when "newConnectionString" doesn't include the new property - "authenticated", it pass)

Is there a solution to handle a custom property for the connectionString (or for dbConnection itself)?
Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to (ab)use the ConnectionString for this information? However, it is not clear at all what means "since there are several operation of Open the connection, I need to handle an indication if the connectionString was already overwritten or no"

Comment: the user tries to connect to DB with user X, and my code should, in specific cases to change the user to user Y. When I already changes the user to Y, I have to keep this info for the next time that getting this dbConnection

Comment: I can't try to connect with the given credentials because of additional flow that I have to run ONLY in the first time of this dcConnection open operation. that's why I must keep it on dbConnection itself.